# Creating a text file in r and saving results in it

Tags: r

I want to use this command

```
write.table(results,file=path.txt,col.names=F,quote=F)
```

I am new to programming, do I have to create a file named path.txt from r program. If yes then pls share how. Thanks.

Comment: you need to write quotation marks around the file `write.table(results,file="path.txt",col.names=F,quote=F) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find this stuff on other pages. As @lebatsnok already mentioned, put quotation marks around the path.txt.

You can write your results using the following 2 lines of code:

```
pathToFile <- "results.txt"
write.table(results,file=pathToFile,col.names=F,quote=F)
```

Comment: You can find it in `help(write.table)` as well.